# How do I copy a directory that is inside of my main bundle to an NSPasteBoard?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have been tearing my hair trying different combinations of file paths and different types but basically what I am trying to do is copy a folder called "test" that is inside of my resources folder.

Copying folders onto the `NSPasteBoard` works when I give an absolute path (ex: /Users/dw/src/Menulet) but it doesn't work when I try using my mainBundle's resource path.
Here is the code I currently have:

```
NSString *resourceFolder = [[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                          resourcePath]] absoluteString];

NSPasteboard *pboard = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard];
[pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLPboardType] owner:nil];

NSString *SDKPathString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@test/",
                                                        resourceFolder];
NSURL *SDKPathURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:SDKPathString];

[pboard writeObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObject:SDKPathURL]];
```

The result is that it can't find the file:

`__CFPasteboardIssueSandboxExtensionForPath: error for [/Users/dw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Menulet-bvwpfkjlcufhxubvaxubgnubtfgi/Build/Products/Debug/Menulet.app/Contents/Resources/test]`

How can I copy the directory?

[image: Screenshot of problem]

**Edit:**
[image: Problem persists]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you're missing a `'/'` character when you do this:

```
NSString *SDKPathString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@test/",
                                                    resourceFolder];
```

Indeed resourceFolder is a path, I usually use something like this instead:

```
NSString* SDKPathString= [resourceFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"test"];
```

Even if in your case you could simply correct the error by putting a `'/'` character before `"test"`.But I think this is more mnemonic.

**Update**

Isn't said that if you create a group Xcode also creates a folder. If you want to be sure that Xcode does so, create a folder with finder and drag it to the project. Check these options:

[image]

This way the folder is actually created, and also added to the bundle.

**Update 2**

You shouldn't try to move your directory inside the project folder to put into the right place, instead put it wherever you want in the bundle, provided that the directory is copied in the bundle.

Once did so, the bundle will manage everything for you. So just search the directory using:

```
- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name ofType:(NSString *)extension;
```

So in your case:

```
NSBundle* bundle= [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *SDKPathString = [ bundle pathForResource: @"test" ofType: @""];
```

Comment: I wish this were the problem. But sadly this did not fix it. I a message dialog box saying "The file "test" could not be opened because there is no such file".

Comment: I added a screenshot of the problem

Comment: "there is no such file" but you are pasting a directory URL.Ok, I'll see the screenshot.

Comment: I am using `NSDragOperationCopy` so it tries to copy the contents at that URL.

Comment: It seems like for mistake you removed the directory inside the project folder. Try re-adding it.

Comment: I readded it but it gives `__CFPasteboardIssueSandboxExtensionForPath: error for [/Users/dw/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Menulet-bvwpfkjlcufhxubvaxubgnubtfgi/Build/Products/Debug/Menulet.app/Contents/Resources/test]` error again

Comment: Are you sure that the directory actually exists? Many times xcode creates groups and make them look like directories, but sometimes they're not really mapped to a directory. Check the project folder.

Comment: The folder doesn't actually exist. Should I just make my own folder called Resources and then add everything to it?

Comment: Create it with finder and then drag the created folder to the project, and check "copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" and "create groups for any added folders". Added this to the answer.

Comment: Seem my new edit. I still have problems. I tried putting the folder outside of the resources folder and used `[mainBundle buildPath]` and then just used the method you described earlier to add the folder name in, and then I tried the method in the screenshot, where I put it in the resources folder.

Comment: See my edit, you can put it wherever you want and then search it inside the bundle.

Comment: NSString *SDKPathString = [ bundle pathForResource: @"test" ofType: @""]; Is returning null.

Comment: Sorry, my fault here. Your case is slightly different, I edited the first update. The second update still applies.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Also needed to call AbsoluteString on the URL but other than that you solved my problem. Now I just need to make it so that it drags the actual directory instead of only the URL now.. Any ideas why this is? (If I hardcode in the directory it actually drags the directory but it isn't working in this case).

Comment: First of all I'm curious to know why you need to do this. This way the user will access to a directory that is inside the app bundle. But let's continue here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22864/cocoa-copy-directory-to-pasteboard